# Jmeter server and Jmeter GUI client remote setup issues

Tags: jmeter, nat

I was trying to setup remote jmeter server and jmeter client.

```
Server public IP : 111.111.111.111
Client public IP : 222.222.222.222
```

I am able to start jmeter server which is on rackspace cloud.

My desktop is behind a firewall with a NAT public IP address. I opened the port 1099 on firewall and added a public IP for the desktop. Also added remote address on jmeter.properties on desktop and started jmeter GUI client.

when i hit remote start from client i am able to see the request reached to jmeter server by this console log

> Starting the test on host 111.111.111.111:1099 @ Wed Apr 25 17:40:09 UTC 2012 (1335375609190)"

but on client i am getting anything and when i checked jmeter-server.log there was some errors:

```
2012/04/25 17:42:36 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 222.222.222.222; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl_Stub.testStarted(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:226)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
    ... 8 more
```

Please suggest me what i am doing wrong here, i am able to telnet server on port 1099 from client and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you disabled any firewalls/antivirus software on the remote machine as well?

Also, in addition to the port being opened, your local antivirus software could be denying the connection.

I ran into similar issues and found that disabling antivirus software on both machines helped.

Comment: My application and my desktop was running on an Linux OS and there is no antivirus. Anyway thanks for the advise. I ended up in setting up jmeter on individual machines.

Answer (score 0):

You must change host file of your client (GUI), to this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx localhost <your computer name>
```

Which: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is real local IP of your client, such as 192.168.1.5

Hope this help.